# why this thread doesnt run parelally?

Tags: python, ffmpeg-python

Hi I have the following code:

```
def record_video(task_id):    

    (
        ffmpeg
        .input('a.mp4', t=t)
        .output(f'{task_id}.mp4')
        .run()
    )


thread = Thread(target=record_video, args=(f'{uuid.uuid1()}.mp4'))

thread.start()

print('end job')
```

The idea is that `print('end job')` runs first, but anyway this waits until record_video thread ends, how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the global interpreter lock (GIL) in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html : *In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.* - yours is a case of "computational resources of multi-core machines".